# reinitializing environment in shared library

Tags: c, perl, openmp

I am writing an OpenMP environment management module for use with perl scripts, and I ran into an issue when utilizing Inline::C for for generating bindings that allow the compiled code (in this case, C) to be called directly.

https://github.com/oodler577/p5-OpenMP-Environment/blob/master/examples/02-inline-c-omp.pl

After some research, I determined that it is expected behavor for the environment to be initialized via `getenv` (`env.c` in libgomp). In the case of a shared library (.so) it exhibits the same behavior on "load" that an a standalone binary with OpenMP exhibits on "run". This is fine, I understand.

My question is, how can I reinitialize the environment as portably as possible and without adding boiler plate code to each inlined C function? Is there a way to "force" a reinitialization of the environment?

The use case here is that, within a perl script, I'd like to update environmental variables such as `OMP_NUM_THREADS` and have it be respected on subsequent calls.

If I do need to resort to adding some boiler plate to read the environment, that's fine. I'd prefer that than having to account for these things as a function parameter. Is there a proper function to call to do this generally? In libgomp?

thank you

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to reload `libgomp.so` and force it to reparse the environment variables each time you change an environment variable in the Perl script.. Instead, could you for example call `omp_set_num_threads()` from `$oenv->omp_num_threads()` instead of setting `$ENV{OPM_NUM_THREADS}` ?

Comment: See also [How can a GNU Fortran / OpenMP program set and retrieve the stacksize-var ICV?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53378713/2173773)

Comment: For reference, [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgomp/env.c#L1414) is the function in `libgomp.so` that parses the environment variables..

Comment: Thank you. The Perl module is meant to affect `%ENV` only;  I was hoping that utilizing C code via Inline::C would provide the semantics that allowed the script to "set" the number of threads (and other things) by affecting the environment only and not needing to actually call the runtime functions that set those. Thank your the help.